# Google Cloud Function - Video Intelligence

Tags: google-cloud-platform, object-detection, object-recognition, video-intelligence-api

I know how to trigger a video intelligence request for object tracking / object detection with Google Cloud as following :

```
video_client = videointelligence.VideoIntelligenceServiceClient()
features = [videointelligence.enums.Feature.OBJECT_TRACKING]
operation = video_client.annotate_video(gs_video_path, features=features)
```

How can I trigger the same function for brand detection, scene detection, OCR, speech recognition and celebrity recognition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To trigger the same function for brand detection (LOGO_RECOGNITION?), scene detection (SHOT_CHANGE_DETECTION?), TEXT_DETECTION and SPEECH_TRANSCRIPTION, you can replace `OBJECT_TRACKING` by, respectively, `LOGO_RECOGNITION`, `SHOT_CHANGE_DETECTION`, `TEXT_DETECTION` or `SPEECH_TRANSCRIPTION`.
Reference:
[Available client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/libraries#available-client-libraries) (For example, [Python for the v1p3beta1](https://googleapis.dev/python/videointelligence/latest/gapic/v1p3beta1/types.html))

[Celebrity recognition](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/celebrity-recognition) is a restricted access feature. It is intended for use by media & entertainment companies or their approved partners on professionally-produced media.
You can find more details in the [Celebrity recognition](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/celebrity-recognition) documentation on how to request access.